# obtaining access_token Http v1 FCM flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I obtain an access_token for fcm HTTP v1.
I've read many questions but no one has helped me.
I use php (backend) and flutter (client).
I tried this (getToken.php):

```
<?php

function base64UrlEncode($text)
{
    return str_replace(
        ['+', '/', '='],
        ['-', '_', ''],
        base64_encode($text)
    );
}

$authConfigString = file_get_contents("key.json");

// Parse service account details
$authConfig = json_decode($authConfigString);

// Read private key from service account details
$secret = openssl_get_privatekey($authConfig->private_key);

// Create the token header
$header = json_encode([
    'typ' => 'JWT',
    'alg' => 'RS256'
]);

// Get seconds since 1 January 1970
$time = time();

$payload = json_encode([
    "iss" => $authConfig->client_email,
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging",
    "aud" => "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "exp" => $time + 3600,
    "iat" => $time
]);

// Encode Header
$base64UrlHeader = base64UrlEncode($header);

// Encode Payload
$base64UrlPayload = base64UrlEncode($payload);

// Create Signature Hash
$result = openssl_sign($base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $signature, $secret, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

// Encode Signature to Base64Url String
$base64UrlSignature = base64UrlEncode($signature);

// Create JWT
$jwt = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;

//-----Request token------
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion='.$jwt,
    'header'  =>
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$responseText = file_get_contents("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", false, $context);

$response = json_decode($responseText);


$senzaSpaziACapo = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $response->access_token);

echo $senzaSpaziACapo;

?>
```

In flutter I tried this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> message = {
        "message": {
          "token": token["token"],
          'data': {
            'idUtente': map["idSecondaPersona"],
            'idSecondaPersona': map["idUtente"],
            'idChat': map["idChat"],
            'messaggio': receivedAction.buttonKeyInput,
            'creazione': currentTimestamp.toString(),
            'nome': nome,
            'idNotifica': token["idNotifica"].toString(),
          },
        }
      };

      var tokenn = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://$ip/getToken.php"));
      var risToken = tokenn.body;

      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(fcmUrl),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
              'Bearer $risToken',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(message),
      );
```

However it returns "error": {"code": 403,"message": "SenderId mismatch","status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"}

Why?
Thanks!